# How to define specific field tokenization on Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, tokenize

I am using logstash to index some mysql data on elasticsearch:

```
input {
    jdbc {
      // JDBC configurations
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => ""
        document_type => ""
        document_id => ""
        hosts => [ "" ]
    }
}
```

When checking results I found that elasticsearch automatically tokenizes the text like this:

```
"Foo/Bar" -> "Foo", "Bar"
"The thing" -> "The", "thing"
"Fork, Knife" -> "Fork", "Knife"
```

Well, that is ok for most of my fields. But there is one specific field that I'd like to have a custom tokenizer. It is a comma separated field (or semi-colon separated). So it should be:

```
"Foo/Bar" -> "Foo/Bar"
"The thing" -> "The thing"
"Fork, Knife" -> "Fork", "Knife"
```

I wander if there is a way to configure this on my logstash configuration.

**UPDATE:**

This is one example of the index that I have. The specific field is `kind`:

```
{
  "index-name": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "My-type": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "kind": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "",
        "number_of_shards": "",
        "number_of_replicas": "",
        "uuid": "",
        "version": {
          "created": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's possible. Can you share your current mapping and the name of the field you'd like to be tokenized differently?

Comment: Hey @Val, I've just added to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do so by using an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

First delete your current index:

```
DELETE index_name
```

Then create the template for your index with the appropriate mapping for the `kind` field, like this:

```
PUT _template/index_name
{
  "template": "index-name",
  "mappings": {
    "My-type": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "kind": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can run Logstash again and the index will be re-created with the proper mapping.

Comment: Thanks. So, I'll need to add this additional "create index" step on my workflow. I wander if I create the index only with the `kind` property it would still work. OK, I have to test it. Thanks, it was very helpful.

Comment: Creating this template needs to be done **only once**. Once it's there, you don't need to do it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the right answer for this question is: you cannot do it by logstash. So I had to add an additional step as follow.

I finally got this done following the path showed by @Val. Thanks, pal. So, what I had to do was to create the index before the logstash ETL with a specific tokenizer:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "simple_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "simple_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "simple_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "template": "my-index",
  "mappings": {
    "my-type": {
      "properties": {
        "kind": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "simple_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a tokenizer by comma to the `kind` field. After that, I can perform the logstash etl and it won't overwrite the `kind` properties.

Comment: Of course you can do it via Logstash, since you can override the logstash template with your own.

Comment: Well, so even this is not the perfect answer.